# SQL nested IIF function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, isnull

I try to make a complicated formula in SQL with nested IIF function. There are many IFF's in this formula. But somehow Microsoft query will not take the statement:
[image]

```
SELECT

IIF (system_Machine.Machine_omschrijving IN ('BE'),
IIF (PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width is NULL,
IIF (PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth is NULL, PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width, PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth)
,
IIF(PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth is NULL,
IIF(PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width is NULL, PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth, PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width)
,
PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth-PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width+PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width-PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width)
)))
[res] ,

PD_Packaging.Packaging_Itemnr,  
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Description,  
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Width,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Weight,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Weightgm2,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Overlap,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Verstrekking,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_CategoryName,    
PD_Main.Main_StatusID,  
PD_Main.Main_Itemnr,
system_Machine.Machine_omschrijving,   
PD_Main.Main_Product,   
PD_Main.Main_WidthTobeInvoiced,  
PD_Main.Main_AssemblingRollDiameter,  
PD_Main.Main_AssemblingRollLength,  
PD_Main.Main_LabelArea,    
PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width,  
PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width,  
PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth

FROM testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_Packaging PD_Packaging    
LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_Main
ON PD_Packaging.Packaging_ID = PD_Main.Main_AssemblingPackagingSingleRollID AND PD_Main.Main_StatusID = 2

LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_FleeceRecipe  
ON PD_Main.Main_ID = PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_MainID AND FleeceRecipe_Preferred = 1    

LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.BOM_Results  
ON PD_Main.Main_Itemnr = BOM_Results.Item_Number

LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.system_Machine  
ON BOM_Results.SelMachineID = system_Machine.Machine_id

WHERE (PD_Packaging.Packaging_CategoryName='STRETCH')  AND (PD_Main.Main_Itemnr = 406181)
```

I also tried a small example with another ISNULL function, but the outcome is "Unexpected RES behind the select columnlist. I do not understand what is my mistake.

```
SELECT

IIF (system_Machine.Machine_omschrijving IN ('BE'),
IIF (ISNULL(FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width), 3,4))

[res] ,

PD_Packaging.Packaging_Itemnr,  
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Description,  
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Width,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Weight,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Weightgm2,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Overlap,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_Verstrekking,   
PD_Packaging.Packaging_CategoryName,    
PD_Main.Main_StatusID,  
PD_Main.Main_Itemnr,
system_Machine.Machine_omschrijving,   
PD_Main.Main_Product,   
PD_Main.Main_WidthTobeInvoiced,  
PD_Main.Main_AssemblingRollDiameter,  
PD_Main.Main_AssemblingRollLength,  
PD_Main.Main_LabelArea,    
PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width,  
PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width,  
PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth

FROM testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_Packaging PD_Packaging    
LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_Main
ON PD_Packaging.Packaging_ID = PD_Main.Main_AssemblingPackagingSingleRollID AND PD_Main.Main_StatusID = 2

LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_FleeceRecipe  
ON PD_Main.Main_ID = PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_MainID AND FleeceRecipe_Preferred = 1    

LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.BOM_Results  
ON PD_Main.Main_Itemnr = BOM_Results.Item_Number

LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.system_Machine  
ON BOM_Results.SelMachineID = system_Machine.Machine_id

WHERE (PD_Packaging.Packaging_CategoryName='STRETCH')  AND (PD_Main.Main_Itemnr = 406181)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you translate the error messages in english?

Comment: I do see missing third param for the _outer_ IIF which means it is just a syntax error.

Comment: The second screenshot message = Unexpexted [Res] behind the SELECT-columnlist.
I tried also a SWITCH function but without a positive result. Maybe something in the syntax is wrong, but I don't see it. The second example is simple and should work but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors.
The [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function contains three mandatory parts:
condition expression, true value and false value.

You're missing the false expression in the outermost `iif` function in both queries, and also a comma after that (and in the first query, there's one too many closing parenthesis)

In your first query:

```
SELECT

IIF (
    system_Machine.Machine_omschrijving IN ('BE'),
    IIF(PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width is NULL,
        IIF (PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth is NULL, 
             PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width, 
             PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth
        ),
        IIF(PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth is NULL,
            IIF(PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width is NULL, 
                PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth, 
                PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width
            ),
            PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth - PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width + PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width - PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width
        )
    )
/* Missing a false value here...*/) 
-- ) this closing parenthesis shouldn't be here. Instead, there should be a comma.
[res] ,
```

And as for the second query:

```
SELECT

IIF (system_Machine.Machine_omschrijving IN ('BE'),
    IIF (ISNULL(FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width), 3,4)
    -- missing a false value here
) -- missing a comma here

[res] ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested case statements instead.

One thing I noticed, there is no else option if `Machine_omschrijving IN ('BE')` does not evaluate to true.

With case statements, the `ELSE` is optional. If not returned, it will just return `NULL`

```
SELECT
    case 
        when system_Machine.Machine_omschrijving IN ('BE') 
        Then
            case 
                when PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width is NULL
                Then
                    Case 
                        when PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth is NULL
                        Then PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width
                        Else PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth
                    End
                Else
                    Case 
                        when PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth is NULL
                        then
                            case 
                                when PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width is NULL
                                then PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth
                                Else PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width
                            End
                        Else (PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth-PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width+PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width-PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width)
                    End
            End
    End
    [res] ,


    PD_Packaging.Packaging_Itemnr,  
    PD_Packaging.Packaging_Description,  
    PD_Packaging.Packaging_Width,   
    PD_Packaging.Packaging_Weight,   
    PD_Packaging.Packaging_Weightgm2,   
    PD_Packaging.Packaging_Overlap,   
    PD_Packaging.Packaging_Verstrekking,   
    PD_Packaging.Packaging_CategoryName,    
    PD_Main.Main_StatusID,  
    PD_Main.Main_Itemnr,
    system_Machine.Machine_omschrijving,   
    PD_Main.Main_Product,   
    PD_Main.Main_WidthTobeInvoiced,  
    PD_Main.Main_AssemblingRollDiameter,  
    PD_Main.Main_AssemblingRollLength,  
    PD_Main.Main_LabelArea,    
    PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer1Width,  
    PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_IntermediateLayer2Width,  
    PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_BottomLayerWidth

FROM 
    testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_Packaging PD_Packaging    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_Main ON PD_Packaging.Packaging_ID = PD_Main.Main_AssemblingPackagingSingleRollID AND PD_Main.Main_StatusID = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.PD_FleeceRecipe  ON PD_Main.Main_ID = PD_FleeceRecipe.FleeceRecipe_MainID AND FleeceRecipe_Preferred = 1    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.BOM_Results  ON PD_Main.Main_Itemnr = BOM_Results.Item_Number
    LEFT OUTER JOIN testsystemOBB.dbo.system_Machine  ON BOM_Results.SelMachineID = system_Machine.Machine_id

WHERE 
    (PD_Packaging.Packaging_CategoryName='STRETCH')  AND (PD_Main.Main_Itemnr = 406181)
```

Comment: Still need a comma after the last `end`

Comment: It returns the column name as [res]. I assume that's what the OP was intending.

Comment: I think you're correct about that. My mistake. one more reason to use `AS` for aliases - to avoid confusion